# Magento: print payment information on any email template

Tags: magento

I have made a test putting the var {{var payment_html}} inside the email template "order_update.html" however when Magento sends an email using this template, any payment information is printed on the box "Payment Details". After that, I searched about it and I found out on [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index) that some variables don't make effect for some templates. I would like to know if is possible to show off the payment details on the order update email template.

Does anybody have idea about how to do that?

Comment: you might want to move that question over to http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, sure. Thanks for let me know about this site, I didn't even know it existed. :S